# The cup of coffee has gone cold

Tags: bug, design, meta

[image]

The steam coming from the coffee cup in the favicon blends in with the background on an inactive Chrome tab (OS X). Although it's still **barely visible,** there should be more contrast between the steam and the grey background of the tab.

(If this is intentional, why isn't the steam the **exact same** color as the tab background?)

Comment: Is this the meta icon? I only ask because the main site one has red steam while the meta one has grey.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes.&nbsp;

Comment: what browser / OS do you use? See [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/165773) (on my machine FF and Chrome both show grey steam)

Comment: @gnat Google Chrome 60.0.3112.101

Comment: Here is the link to the meta favicon: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/softwareengineeringmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c5aca3befd82. Certainly, it's not intentional since anyone can change the color theme on Chrome. (on my current theme, the steam is visible when the tab is inactive, but almost invisible on active tab)

Comment: The steam should probably be changed to red.  It's very unlikely that anyone is going to have a red bar in their browser.